# Is there a tool to visualise method calls in Python?

Tags: python, visualization

example:

```
def a():
  pass

def b():
  pass

def c():
  a()
  b()
```

and the tool would show some kind of graph like:

```
c -> a()
  -> b()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print functions as they are called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315389/how-do-i-print-functions-as-they-are-called)

Comment: @karthikr not exactly. What I wish is a tool to visualise the method call flow. If `b()` calls `d()` and more methods follow, the graph will be like a tree with the entrance of the program as the root.

Answer (score 9):

The graph you're looking for is called a call graph. There is a python module to build them:

http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/

Comment: Reading the intro: https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/intro.html, the tools needs to execute the code in order to give you a graph. Is there a tool that can given me the graph without executing it? Because I don't know whether the code is malicious or not in behaviour, so I don't want to run it.

Comment: @DaCruzR, you're better to just run it in your head, or replace the supposed malicious parts of the code with trusted faux values and then run it

Comment: This repository is now archived, and builds are failing - [Github](https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph/blob/master/docs/index.rst)