# Call stack of functions within a repository

Tags: python, callstack

For a given Python script in a repository foobar, how can I see all the functions called that are within foobar? Trace functions and profilers give me all calls, whereas I only want to see how the program traverses the repository.

A few notes:

- The repo is mostly Python with a few cython and C++ files
- I'm aware of questions like [How do I print functions as they are called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315389/how-do-i-print-functions-as-they-are-called) that recommend `sys` trace functions
- [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/master/) would be awesome if it were limited to the functions defined within my repo foobar.

UPDATE:
I've done this with `python -m trace --listfuncs my_script.py`, and then filtering the output for files that are on the directory path. This is okay, but I would prefer a cleaner way of traversing the call structure of the repo's functions.

Comment: What do you mean by repository?  Repository is not really a python term.

Comment: Github repository