# Trace specific functions in Python to capture high-level execution flow

Tags: python, trace, stack-trace, execution

Python offers tracing through its [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module. There are also custom solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315389/how-do-i-print-functions-as-they-are-called). But these approaches capture most low-level executions, inside-and-out of most/every library you use. Other than deep-dive debugging this isn't very useful.

It would be nice to have something that captures only the highest-level functions laid out in your pipeline. For example, if I had:

```
def funct1():
    res = funct2()
    print(res)

def funct2():
    factor = 3
    res = funct3(factor)
    return(res)

def funct3(factor):
    res = 1 + 100*factor
    return(res)
```

...and called:

```
funct1()
```

...it would be nice to capture:

```
function order:
    - funct1
    - funct2
    - funct3
```

I have looked at:

- [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html)
- [tracefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315566/1639594)
- [sys.settrace](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html)
- [trace.py](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-trace-python-scripts-using-trace-py/)

I am happy to manually mark the functions inside the scripts, like we do with Docstrings. Is there a way to add "hooks" to functions, then track them as they get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a decorator to track which functions are called.  Here is an example that allows you to keep track of what nesting level the function is called at:

```
class Tracker:
    level = 0

    def __init__(self, indent=2):
        self.indent = indent

    def __call__(self, fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(' '*(self.indent * self.level) + '-' + fn.__name__)
            self.level += 1
            out = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            self.level -= 1
            return out
        return wrapper


track = Tracker()

@track
def funct1():
    res = funct2()
    print(res)

@track
def funct2():
    factor = 3
    res = funct3(factor)
    return(res)

@track
def funct3(factor):
    res = 1 + 100*factor
    return(res)
```

It uses the class variable `level` to keep track of how many functions have been called and simply prints out the the function name with a space `indent`.  So calling `funct1` gives:

```
funct1()
# prints:
-funct1
  -funct2
    -funct3
# returns:
301
```

Depending on how you want to save the output, you can use the logging module for the output