# How to implement an implicit logger in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to add some helpful logging to a Python codebase.

I'm looking to add logging roughly of the form:

```
[2022-01-06 10:00:01] function foo called with args x=1, y=22, z=3
[2022-01-06 10:00:05] function foo returned 1416
[2022-01-06 10:00:13] function bar called with args w=1416
[2022-01-06 10:00:16] function bar returned None
```

I could do this by wrapping all functions in the codebase with a decorator, but is there a better way? At least to indicate the timestamp and order in which functions are being called.

I could implement the decorator:

```
def logthis(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(f'Calling {func.__name__} with args={args} and kwargs={kwargs}')
        ans = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.info(f'Function {func.__name__} returned {ans}')
        return ans
    return inner

@logthis
def foo(x, y, z):
   return x+y+z

@logthis
def bar(w):
   return None
```

This works reasonably well; provided I'm happy to add it across my whole codebase.

Comment: Nope, a decorator is your best bet.

Comment: You'd need to explicitly log the parameters and return values, and doing that would naturally be ordered, but timestamp can easily be added - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#displaying-the-date-time-in-messages

Comment: I really want to avoid adding hundreds of lines of code just to log function invocations. I'll keep looking for now.

Comment: Nit: your decorator should return `ans`, not call the function a second time.

Comment: Logging *every single function in your codebase* is going to be massive overhead and not as useful as you're thinking.

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing it now, at least around the high level entry points. My code is basically a pipeline, so not too worried about the overhead right now.

Comment: You could use [`sys.setrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) to trace and log the function calls. There's an example of using it in the article [Tracing a Program As It Runs](https://pymotw.com/3/sys/tracing.html) on the [Python 3 Module of the Week](https://pymotw.com/3/#python-3-module-of-the-week) website. You could make it selective if you wished…

Comment: Also see [How do I print functions as they are called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315389/how-do-i-print-functions-as-they-are-called)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `inspect` module. I typically use it to implement a "Get the filepath of the function that called this function" method I use for various reasons. `inspect.stack()` ([see this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack)) may be what you are looking for as you can go up the list of callers and create info about it.

From there I think the only problem you'd have is how to log the time. Another idea is two create a wrapper for entire classes or a function that you pass `__locals__()` to that gets all functions and applies a decorator to them. That method is going somewhat into meta programming since you'd have to reconstruct the class objects /update/wrap all of their functions like you have and whatnot, but it could save you a fair amount of tedious work.

Also see the [traceback module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html).