Python Recursive Method Wrapping
I need a way to wrap not just one method, but a way to wrap all callees of that method upon its call, and all callees of the callees as well (i.e. recursive wrapping). Is this possible? If so, what is the proper way to do it? If it's not possible, what is the closest equivalent? My ultimate goal is to achieve this:
# Ultimate Goal: Develop a custom solution that dynamically logs subsequent method calls that are **direct continuations of an initial method's execution path**.

# Recursive Definition - Methods that are **direct continuations of an initial method's execution path** are methods that satisfy one or more of the below properties:
    # 0. Base case: The initial method wrapped by entry_point automatically satisfied the definition of: **direct continuations of an initial method's execution path**
    # 1. Methods called within another method that recursively satisfies: **direct continuations of an initial method's execution path**
    # 2. Methods called as a subsequent chain (i.e. ().() ) of a method that recursively satisfies: **direct continuations of an initial method's execution path**
    # 3. Methods that are called as part of the process that delivers the direct response from an external endpoint that corresponds to a specific client-side method that makes a request to an external endpoint, given that the client-side method that makes the request satisfies: **direct continuations of an initial method's execution path**


Isn't this the same as your last question?

I pointed you to another question that shows how to trace calls.

This is slightly different. I am looking for a way to do of recursive wrapping.

That's an XY problem. Your goal is the same, isn't it?

Wrap all your functions in a decorator that checks a global flag variable to determine if they should log. Then set the flag in the top-level function.

However, this will only wrap the functions you've defined, it won't log calls to built-in or third-party functions.

What I'm looking for is essentially the latter of what you mentioned.

The latter of what? You want to log the functions you can't modify? I think the link to tracing code may be what you need.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315389/how-do-i-print-functions-as-they-are-called
